# Adding a column dynamically in to a grid view using linq

Tags: asp.net

I have a grid view to which I bind data in to the grid view using a linq query. I need to add a separate column to that grid view. How can I add it?

I used the query shown below:

```
DataTable dt = Common.dc.TblIssueDetails.Where(id => id.AssetId == 
LeAsset.EditValue.getInteger()).Select(id => new
    {
        Select=false,
        id.TblStoreStock.TblStock.TblItem.ItemName,
        id.TblIssueMaster.IssueDate,
        Quantity=0
    }).getDataTable();
```

Comment: Just add your new column in the Select clause, like `,NewCol = "Value"`

Comment: What column do you want to add? where are the data for this separate column?

Answer (score 0):

Add another one property to your anonymous class:

```
DataTable dt = Common.dc.TblIssueDetails.Where(id => id.AssetId == 
LeAsset.EditValue.getInteger()).Select(id => new
         {
           Select=false,
           id.TblStoreStock.TblStock.TblItem.ItemName,
           id.TblIssueMaster.IssueDate,
           Quantity=0,
           SomeSeparateColumnName = someData // someData is data that you want to write to separate column.
          }).getDataTable();
```